# How to convert this select statement into a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have this select statement that displays the text (content) of a **pl/sql script** :

```
select text
from DBA_source
where type like '%PROCEDURE%' and name like '%JOB_HISTORY%'
order by line;
```

I want to convert this into a stored procedure in such a way that the 'name' condition of the select statement should be taken as an input and should not be pre defined as show like '%job_history%.

How can this be done ?

Comment: You probably want a stored function, not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function, not a stored procedure:

```
create type proc_tab is table of DBA_source.text%type;
/

create function select_procedure(p_name in film.title%type) return proc_tab
is
    l_proc_tab proc_tab := proc_tab();
    n integer := 0;
begin
    select text
    bulk collect into l_proc_tab
    from DBA_source
    where type like '%PROCEDURE%' and name like '%' || p_name || '%'
    order by line;
    return l_proc_tab;
end;
/
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should at least be a good start.

Comment: This looks like it'd result in an RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) situation.  Is there not a way to just return the result table from the query generates?

Comment: You can do things involving cursors, but that's not what OP asked for.

Comment: It is quite useless to define an object type for a single scalar. Simply do `create type proc_tab is table of DBA_source.text%type;` and then inside the function `SELECT text BULK COLLECT INTO l_proc_tab FROM DBA_source WHERE ...; return l_proc_tab;`